# Take down the helicopter in Just Cause

Tags: just-cause-2

I'm playing Just Cause 2, but can't figure out how I should take down the helicopter in the mission where I need to protect the technichian. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faction takeover missions, the ones that require you to protect a technician while trying he goes about hacking into the site's systems, usually end with a 'boss battle', where the site's commander comes attacking in a helicopter or armored vehicle.

At this point, look around for a [mounted minigun](http://justcause.wikia.com/wiki/Minigun), which can be detached by tapping the jump key (default: Space), so that you can aim upwards at the helicopter. This is the best option, as the minigun is extremely powerful and has unlimited ammo. If you can't find one, then you just have to make use with whatever is at hand. There should be a lot of dead guards around the area whose machine guns should be useful in taking down the helicopter. If you have the time (which you usually wouldn't), you can also look around to see if there's a helicopter nearby which you can use.

Comment: I do indeed have a mounted minigun, but the helicopter is flying too high so I can't point on the helicopter with the minigun.

Comment: @kanarifugl As mentioned, you can detach the minigun by pressing space

Comment: Once detached, I believe the minigun's ammo becomes limited, so it's best to only detach it when absolutely necessary. On a semi-related note: if all else fail, you could always try to grapple onto the helicopter and attempt to hijack it.

Comment: @Nolonar No, that's not true, both from personal experience and the wiki

Comment: Even detached, miniguns have unlimited ammo and are amazing. Miniguns are the solution to so, so many problems that you might encounter in JC2.

Answer (score 10):

I've found the most useful way to be hooking to the helicopter and throwing the pilot out. This gets rid of the helicopter problem really quickly, and it gives you a mighty weapon against the rest of the enemies.

Comment: Yeah I always do that aswell, grapple, pull the pilot out then laughing evilly I start shooting stuff with the helicopter.

Comment: True. I always try to hijack the helicopter, it's like 2 birds with a stone - you save the technician, and get a travel+ammo combo too. :D